# 2 questions about python/ My program doesn't start

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error, ascii, startup

Hello I'm a beginner at python.
So I made my program.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

def baslangic():
    print "Sonsuza kadar giden sayi programina hos geldin"
    print "Bana merhaba der misin?"
    cevap=raw_input("Evet ya da hayır= ")
    if cevap.lower()==("evet"):
        print "O zaman haydi programa geçelim"
        program()
    elif cevap.lower()=="hayir" or cevap.lower()==("hayir"):
        sys.exit("Cyka Blyat")
    else:
        os.system("cls")


        print "Yanlis bir sey girdiniz."
        print "Lutfen sadece evet ya da hayir giriniz."
        print baslangic()








def program():
    sayi = int("1")
    while 1:
        print "Şu anki sayimiz " + str(sayi)
        sayi = sayi + 1

baslangic()
```

Basically what this does is asking for user input (I'm studying what I learned)
and after that input (if it is yes) it just types all numers to infinite.
It works like charm in idle(python gui) but it doesn't work in cmd.
This is the error.

```
C:\Users\Doruk\Desktop>sayi.py
  File "C:\Users\Doruk\Desktop\sayi.py", line 4
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xfd' in file C:\Users\Doruk\Desktop\sayi.py on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

I look at other threads and they say

```
   Add this at the beginning 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

But it doesn't work on mine :(
When I write crcp in cmd it returns me 
Active code page: 857

And 2nd question:
How can I make that numbers slower like seconds?
Maybe tomorrow I will make a clock.

Oh also forget to mention:
Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 1):

These two things need to be at the top of the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Also if you want the output to be slower try putting

```
import time
```

at the top

and adding

```
time.sleep(1)
```

to the while loop

edit:

try doing it like this

```
print u'weird unicode string'
```

See how the u is added to the front of the string

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a line at the beginning

Try this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you have just too many abnormalities in ur code you could just help urself by removing the foreign characters in your code like "ç" which is definitely a NON-ASCII character.
instead of this:

```
print "O zaman haydi programa geçelim"
```

Use this:

```
print "O zaman haydi programa gecelim"
```

Maybe that would help atleast for now

And for your next question you need the sleep method

```
import time
time.sleep(amnt_in_secs)
```

Comment: I meant you needed to change all stuffs like that so u don't get to have same syntax error. Another is your `print "Şu anki sayimiz "` in your program func.